# How to fix test with mocha/chai throwing "app.address()" error on NestJS API?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, nestjs

I'm trying to test my API's routes with Mocha and Chai but all I get is an "TypeError".

Here is my main.ts file :

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

export async function bootstrap(): Promise<any> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Cats example')
    .setDescription('The cats API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('cats')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  return await app.listen(3000);
}
const appServer = bootstrap();
export default appServer;
```

Initially the "bootstrap" function wasn't returning anything but I made it return the app.listen to export it in the end.

Here is my test file :

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
import 'mocha';
import appServer from '../src/main';

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('first test', () => {
  it('should return hello world', async () => {
    const res = await chai.request(appServer).get('/notes');
    chai.expect(res.text).to.equal('hello');
  });
});
```

This is what I get when lauching "npm test". The error occurs in "node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js" file.

> TypeError : app.address() is not a function

I tried to console.log(app) in the "request.js" file and this is what I got

> promise { < pending > }

And I also tried to right this in main.ts

```
console.log(app.address())
```

But Visual Code warns me immediately with this error

> Property 'address' does not exist on type 'INestApplication'.ts(2339)

Is NestFactory compatible with Chai ? It feels like the "app" I'm exporting in "main.ts" doesn't fit with what shai's request needs. I'm confused.

**Here is the edited accepted solution to make it work properly**

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
import 'mocha';
import { AppModule } from '../src/app.module';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('first test', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();
    app = module.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  it('should return hello world', async () => {
    const res = await chai.request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/notes');
    chai.expect(res.text).to.equal('hello');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, chai-http expects an Express/Connect application or a raw Node HTTP server. What you will probably need in you `chai.request` is to use `app.getHttpServer()` so that you get the underlying server, as Nest is really an opinionated syntactical wrapper around Express/Fastify.

---

## Edit

As the `SwaggerModule` is not needed in the test context, I would suggest following something similar to this:

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
import 'mocha';
import { AppModule } from '../src/app.module';

describe('first test', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();
    app = module.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  it('should return hello world', async () => {
    const res = await chai.request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/notes');
    chai.expect(res.text).to.equal('hello');
  });

});
```

From here if you need to override any services, guards, pipes, interceptors, or filters you can use the corresponding `override*()` method before chaining to the `compile()` call. This is a very similar method to how to test with `supertest` as well.

Comment: I am not able to write appServer.getHttpServer() as visual studio tells me "Property 'getHttpServer' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>' ".
I think the test is running while the function "bootstrap" isn't even loaded and hasn't returned anything. That would explain the error, but still I can't see another way to do it.

Comment: Then you need to make the testing function `async` and `await` the application. 

What would probably be better is to use the `Test.createTestingModule()` functionality from the `@nestjs/testing` package.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this. How do I make the testing function await the application ?

Comment: Quick question: do you need the Swagger module in your test application?

Comment: No, not in the test

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer to show how to create a testing module for purposes like this. This approach is described in the testing docs on the nest website using supertest and jest instead of chai and mocha, but the idea is all the same

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot for your time Jay I appreciate it